# Angular - Unable to get data out of object within an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to make some radio buttons in my Angular page that get their value from an API call and am having some trouble with it.

My code does not compile and is showing me these errors in the console:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '[{ name: string; value:
> number; default: number; }]'. [ng]  [ng] 103
> this.preSelectedPaymentOptions = this.paymentMethod.payments.default
> === 1;
>
> Property 'default' does not exist on type '[{ name: string; value:
> number; default: number; }]'. [ng]  [ng] 103
> this.preSelectedPaymentOptions = this.paymentMethod.payments.default
> === 1;
>
> Property 'name' does not exist on type '[{ name: string; value:
> number; default: number; }]'. [ng]  [ng] 105
> console.log('Metoda plačila: ',this.paymentOptions.name);

My data looks like this in console.log:

```
hasACashDiscount:0
payments: Array(2)
0: {name: 'Card', value: 0, default: 1}
1: {name: 'Cash', value: 3, default: 0}
```

I have created a *model.ts* file. It looks like this:

```
export interface PaymenyOptions {
  hasACashDiscount: number;
  payments: [{
      name: string;
      value: number;
      default: number;
  }];
}
```

In my *component.ts* file this is how I'm getting the data from the API call subscription:

```
getPaymentOptions() {
  this.cartService.getPaymenyOptions().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.paymentMethod = data;
      this.paymentOptions = this.paymentMethod.payments;
      this.preSelectedPaymentOptions = this.paymentMethod.payments.default === 1;
      console.log('All data: ', this.paymentMethod);
      console.log('Payment methods: ',this.paymentOptions.name);
      console.log('Preselected method: ', this.preSelectedPaymentOptions);
    }, error => {
      console.log('Error', error);
    });
}
```

and this is how I'm showing it in HTML:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let payment of paymentOptions;let i = index">
  <ion-icon name="today-outline"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>{{ payment.name }}</ion-label>
  <ion-radio slot="end" [value]="payment.value"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>ž
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paymentMethod.payments` is an array.

To get (filter) the objects with `default === 1`, you should use `Array.filter()` method.

```
this.preSelectedPaymentOptions = this.paymentMethod.payments.filter(x => x.default === 1);
```

To get the objects' names as an array, you have to use `Array.map()` method.

```
console.log('Payment methods: ',this.paymentOptions.map(x => x.name);
```

```
export interface PaymenyOptions {
  hasACashDiscount: number;
  payments: [{
      name: string;
      value: number;
      default: number;
  }];
}
```

Based on your current interface, the `payments` property is an array but expects a single object only. You should modify it to:

```
export interface PaymenyOptions {
  hasACashDiscount: number;
  payments: {
      name: string;
      value: number;
      default: number;
  }[];
}
```

to allow the array can have multiple objects.

Comment: Your anwser gives me this error: Type '{ name: string; value: number; default: number; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{ name: string; value: number; default: number; }]'.
[ng]   Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.
[ng] 
[ng] 103         this.preSelectedPaymentOptions = this.paymentMethod.payments.filter(x => x.default === 1);

Comment: Change the `payments` property in `PaymentOptions` interface to type: `{ name: string; value: number; default: number; }[]`. Your current property type is an array and expects a single object only.